# Need to generate different session id to identify user without a login system in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to store order details in a database without a login system.how can i generate a id for different users and store in a session variable.please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: have you check below answer

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies instead of sessions for it would vary from user to user i.e. browser to browser so for each user you can save his cookies on his browser itself.

Comment: You can create cookies in php. Refer to php manual to know how to work with cookies in php http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: I tried this:<?php 
setcookie("name","value",time()+$int);
/*name is your cookie's name
value is cookie's value
$int is time of cookie expires*/
?>

Getting Cookie
=============================
<?php 
echo $_COOKIE["your cookie name"];
?>
Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];` it vary for user to user.

Simply check `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];` in database if exists the place order agents that user if not add new user.